# confirm() is not working on my Windows 10 Web App

Tags: javascript, windows, win-universal-app, windows-10, confirm

I am making a Windows 10 Web App (Project Westminster). There is a page that requires user to input something, and there's a 'save' button, and another button that leads to another page of the app.

To prevent user clicking the wrong button and lost his/her data before saving, I implement the JavaScript confirm() method to ask users to confirm before leaving.

This is working on iOS, Android, or Edge browser on Windows 10, but not on the Windows 10 app. The prompt does not show up but the page also does not exit, as if the user has already pressed the "stay here" button.

How can I make this work as expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows will not let you prevent the closing of an app of the user chooses to, so the best way to handle this would be to save the data on the Suspending event and load it again when the app resumes. 
[Here's a sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-activation-events-and-d39c53d5) that might help you get going.